# CSS Absolute positioning and body scrolling

Tags: css, css-position

I need to put an absolute div in the bottom right of a page.

```
.absolute{
   position: absolute;
   right:0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

This works, but with page scroll the right/bottom position is not relative the body width/height but relative the visible area (window).

```
body{
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

I could solve this problem with a wrapping div of style `position:relative, width: 100%;` but I lost the bottom position.

This is what **I want** to get:

[image: Page absolute positioning]

Comment: Use `fixed` or `static` instead of `absolute`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WCLwH/ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set a relative position to your `body` element:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Because so your `.absolute` element will be relative to it and not to the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/WCLwH/1/

```
<body>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="lime"></div>
</body>


<style type="text/css">
body {
  position: relative;
  border:solid 5px blue;
}
.red {
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    border:solid 5px red;
}
.lime {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;right:0px;
    width:250px;height:150px;
    border:solid 5px lime;
}
</style>
```

and with lots of content in the "red box" it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WCLwH/2/

Comment: If I add `margin-bottom` into `.red` and remove `border` from **body**, I'll see `.lime` bottom position the same as `.red`. *// Sorry for bad English* **See this: http://jsfiddle.net/7gqkj8km/**